# Devise Error with MongoMapper

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, devise, mongomapper

I am attempting to add devise to an existing Oauth project.  I have a facebook authentication that works but when I try to add Devise, I can get a devise.rb but cannot run rails generate devise User without a massive error starting with an uninitialized constant comment.

In my gem file:

```
gem 'rails', '4.0.0'
gem 'mongo_mapper', :git => "git://github.com/mongomapper/mongomapper.git", :tag => "v0.13.0.beta2"
gem 'bson_ext'

gem 'foundation-rails'

gem 'omniauth'
gem 'omniauth-facebook', '1.4.0'

gem 'devise'
gem 'mm-devise'
```

Part of the error that I keep getting:

```
.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/mm-devise-1.2/lib/devise/orm/mongo_mapper.rb:24:in `<module:Schema>': uninitialized constant Devise::Schema (NameError)
```

If there is anything else that I can post that will help solve this problem, please let me know.